# Returning array in JSON format stored in PHP SESSION to iOS application not working

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode, mysqli

I have been making basic calls from my website to my iOS application in JSON format.  I will be adding security measures in the future, but right now just trying to get the calls to work (before anyone says how unsecure my calls are!)  These basic calls that I have been making have been working just fine.  Recently I created a response from what was inside a PHP Session and it does not return anything to my application.  I have been scratching my head trying to figure it out and have come to the conclusion that it must be because of the session since normal calls work just fine.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
 session_start();
$link=mysqli_connect('redacted', 'redacted', '', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
$max = count($_SESSION['cart']);
$json = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$max;$i++) {
    $pid = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM atable WHERE PID='$pid'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $json[]=$row;
        }
    }
}
mysqli_close($link);
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Here is my objective-c:

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"theURL"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSArray *theResponses = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                        options:0
                                                          error:NULL];
         NSLog(@"response %@", theResponses);
     }
 }];
```

On a side note I have tested my php script response in postman so I know it works just fine.  I also know my objective-c should be correct as it works with other services.  Any ideas??

Comment: Reduce the problem. Not all of the these systems apply.

Comment: 1/ Does the completionBlock was invoked ?, 2/Are you observed response statusCode

Comment: You will not get the `SESSION` data from your server, because `SESSION` store a `cookie` of `PHP SESSION ID` on browser, and when we work with `web services` there is no browser so there will be no `PHP SESSION ID` and hence the server will not be able to send you any response related with `SESSION`.

Comment: So I have seen apps with shopping carts that are native where if you add something to your cart from the app it persists to the website and vice versa.  How are they doing this then if you cannot use a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for anyone that was wondering the same thing. I realize how stupid I was being!  Of course you can't transfer data from a session to an app!  You can't magically get data from a browser to an unrelated app..